# Java regular express Matcher.group()

Tags: java, regex

Recently, I try to learn how to use regex in java.
I try to match the expression: match(^(21|23)$, $lm) with the following code in java:

```
Pattern pat1 = Pattern.compile("\\((.*)\\,");
Matcher mat1 = pat1.matcher(str);
```

to find ^(21|23)$ this group by:

```
return mat1.group();
```

where I got an exception message java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found

But when I check:

```
mat1.find();
```

It will return true.
So how can I get ^(21|23)$ in this case?

Comment: You need to call `.find()` before `.group()`

Comment: I tested your code and it worked fine after the suggestion by @anubhava to call `mat1.find()` before checking the first group.

Comment: Could you please let us know your exact requirement. Input text you need to match.

Comment: Also, your pattern matches (^(21|23)$ instead of ^(21|23)$. In order to omit the leading parenthesis, do `.group(1)`. This gets the first captured group, whereas `.group()` returns the entire match. Alternatively, you could change your regex to `"\\^.*\\,"` to only match the substring you want.

Comment: Problem solved, thank you guys